# jQuery .hide() causing a ghost touchstart "click" of 2nd button

Tags: jquery, mobile

I have two buttons on a page, I need to hide a "calculate" button so that it is not clicked again and again, but rather users select a "reset" button.

This works great if both buttons are showing but if I hide the calculate button, once it has completed its work, it somehow is automatically executing the reset button even though the reset button is not being clicked.

**This only happens on touch devices**. This works fine if it is run from a browser. It is only the touch devices (ex. iPhone) where the issue is occurring. Any clues? I am using jquery-2.1.1.min

Here is my calculate button:

```
$(document).on( 'touchstart click' ,  '#calculate' ,  function  () {
// do stuff
//hide button now that we are done so users don't keep clicking
$( '#calculate' ).hide();
});
```

Here is my reset button:

```
$(document).on( 'touchstart click' ,  '#reset' ,  function  () {
$( "input.form-control" ).val(0);
});
```

Here is my working example:

http://investingcalculator.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Odd, could it be a browser issue? Aka, Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ends up that I didn't need the touch start. This is working:

```
$('#calculate').on( 'click',  function  () {
// do stuff
//hide button now that we are done so users don't keep clicking
$( '#calculate' ).hide();
});

$('#reset').on( 'click',  function  () {
$( "input.form-control" ).val(0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try without delegating?

```
$('#calculate').on( 'touchstart click',  function  () {
// do stuff
//hide button now that we are done so users don't keep clicking
$( '#calculate' ).hide();
});

$('#reset').on( 'touchstart click',  function  () {
  $( "input.form-control" ).val(0);
});
```

Comment: I get the same result. It triggers the reset button after clicking the calculate button. Very frustrating.

Comment: Please see my answer. I didn't need the touch start in the end. Thanks for your help